# Git rebase - prefers older data in files with conflicts?

Tags: git

I'm on a new branch and made some changes to files. Meanwhile the master branch has changed too, so to incorporate those changes in my branch I would like to use rebase. I checkout the master branch and pull, then going back into my new branch, I do

```
git rebase master
```

Then I'm getting some conflicts, in those files with conflicts, vs-code allows me to resolve the conflicts, however in other lines (in those same files with conflicts), where there are no conflicts, I see that git overwritten my new code (which I committed), and it was overwritten by the older code of my master. Why is that so? Isn't it supposed to be the other way around? I'm rebasing master my new commit should be on top - therefore why my code is being overwritten by the older one from Master?

Comment: It depends.... is your branch made up of multiple revisions? If that's the case, you might be facing conflicts in earlier revisions of the branch, so the final state of the files might be missing _at the time_.

Comment: Oh I see yes that makes sense, and yes there are multiple revisions. In this case what should I do?

Comment: Let me provide the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the branch is made up of many revisions that will be rebased, you might face conflicts on any of the revisions that will be applied and so it's normal that you won't see the final version of the files (with all the changes of the feature branch applied). So just consider the conflicts, add the files when you are done and run `git rebase --continue` so that rebase can apply the pending revisions.

It's still possible that you might want to look at other places, there's nothing that forbids it, just consider that only a subset of the changes might have been applied up to that point (if the conflicted revision is not the last in the rebase).

Comment: Thank you very much yes indeed you were right, after finishing the rebase the newer code was displayed, I'm just new to git so was immediately afraid I did something wrong(:

Comment: No problem.... all of those questions are normal to come up when we are starting to go through this loooong road of learning all of git's tricks/workflows.